# why is service workers offline mode not working

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

I am trying to provide offline access for the app. But the code is not working.

the cache is being created and stores all the files but when i reload the page in offline mode only the data loads, without any styling applied.

chrome version: Version 61.0.3163.100

// app.js

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/sw.js')
        .then(function () {
            console.log('service worker reistered');
        });
}
```

// service worker js

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
      event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('static').then(function (cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/',
                'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css',
                'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                '/index.html',
                '/styles.css',
                '/app.js'
            ]);
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: So the HTML and JS loads, but the CSS does not? Are there any errors in the console when that happens?

Comment: when reloading in offline mode, gives this error `GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
127.0.0.1/:10 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/styles.css net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
127.0.0.1/:32 GET https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
127.0.0.1/:33 GET http://127.0.0.1:8080/app.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
127.0.0.1/:31 GET https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED`

Answer (score 1):

You need a `fetch` handler in your `service-worker.js`. While you're adding items to the cache inside of your `install` handler, you're not responding to `fetch` events by serving items from the cache.

There are some basic examples of using the `install`, `activate`, and `fetch` events to precache and serve content cache-first at, e.g., [this sample](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/prefetch/index.html).

My recommendation is, for a more automated solution, to integrate a tool like [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) (which I work on) into your web app's build process, so that the local resources you need are automatically precached and kept up to date. It can generate a service worker file on your behalf.

Comment: tried this but not working    

`self.addEventListener('fetch', function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        caches.match(event.request)
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                return response;
            } else {
                return fetch(event.request);
            }
        })
    );
})`